# how to log only successfully executed query in yii2 similar like profile log

Tags: php, yii2

I have successfully implemented profile log in yii2 that will log all executed mysql query. But the problem is, it also log the query that are rollback during the process. I want to keep record of all successfully executed query and keep it as backup/mirror. Is there any way i can achieve this. 
I tried using Dbtarget log and commented the following part

```
 public function export() {
        if ($this->db->getTransaction()) {
   // create new database connection, if there is an open transaction
   // to ensure insert statement is not affected by a rollback
this is my comment=>// $this->db = clone $this->db; 
        }
```

But still it did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve by checking category of query in yii2. Each query are categorized in yii2 as query,execution and each execution query starts transaction start and end with rollback or commit. So only save the execution query having that ends with commit category in Dbtarget class.